# using lapply and filter to subset dataframes with a pattern in the filtered columname

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

- Working with R *

I have a list of 16 dataframes in which each dataframe corresponds to a different year. In order to keep order, when I created these dfs, I added a suffix to each columname depending on the year of each df (e.g. the area field of the df in 2002 is called "area_2", and 2003 is "area_3".

Among the DF's columns, there is a field that has two possible values (0 or 1, as representation of a True or False).

I want to create lists of subsets depending on the possible fields of these subsets, such as the rows of each df in which that field is 1, or 0.

If all the fields were named the same way, I could use the line:

```
subset <- lapply(df.list, function(x) dplyr::filter(x, fieldname == "1"))
```

However, the fieldname is differently named in each list member, being "fieldname_2", "fieldname_3"--- all the way to 18 (skipping 8).

The question, then, is whether there is a straightforward way to perform this subsetting, within the list, setting the function to find the fieldname with a pattern and a changing suffix.

a dummy example on which to practice the filtering:

```
valuesx <- c(1,4,3,1,2,5,6,4)
valuesy <- c(4,3,7,1,8,5,2,1)

column_2 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
column_3 <- c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)

df1<- data.frame(value = valuesx, column_2 = column_2)
df2<- data.frame(value = valuesy, column_3 = column_3)

list_df <- list(df1, df2)
```

**Desired outcome: a new list with the rows of each DF in which "column*"==1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this...

```
lapply(list_df,function(x) x[x[,grep("column",names(x))]==1,])

[[1]]
  value column_2
1     1        1
2     4        1
3     3        1
4     1        1

[[2]]
  value column_3
1     4        1
3     7        1
4     1        1
7     2        1
```

The `grep` finds the columns with names including the text `column`, and uses them for the filtering - irrespective of where they are in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

As the column names are different, use an index to subset the `data.frame`s after looping through the `list` with `lapply`

```
new_listdf <- lapply(list_df, function(x) x[x[[2]] == 1, ])
new_listdf
#[[1]]
#  value column_2
#1     1        1
#2     4        1
#3     3        1
#4     1        1

#[[2]]
#  value column_3
#1     4        1
#3     7        1
#4     1        1
#7     2        1
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
list_df %>% 
     map(~ .x %>% 
             filter_at(vars(matches('column')), any_vars(. == 1)))
#[[1]]
#  value column_2
#1     1        1
#2     4        1
#3     3        1
#4     1        1

#[[2]]
#  value column_3
#1     4        1
#2     7        1
#3     1        1
#4     2        1
```